# when will priority queue call compareTo of the elements?

Tags: java, multithreading, priority-queue

I am writing a ai of dots and boxes. I am using the priority queue to contain my edges of boxes. And I make a move by the priority of a box. After a move, I have to update the priority and pool() the head of queue.

Here is some code:

```
   public int compareTo(MyPosition o) {
        if (new Integer(o.getPriority())> new Integer(getPriority())) {
            return 1;
        }else if(new Integer(o.getPriority())== new Integer(getPriority())){
            return 0;
        }else {
            return -1;
        }
        
    }
```

But what the order of my move is not correspond to the priority of queue.
Here is picture (the last number is the priority of edge):

[image]

So could anyone explain why and how to improve it. (I guess the priority queue don't compare the priority after updates.)

Thanks a lot.

Comment: The PriorityQueue won't re-organize itself whenever you update the priority of an item stored in it. In order to update properly, you have to remove the item, update it, and re-add it to the queue. Unfortunately, Java's PriorityQueue supports removals in linear time, and not logarithmic time.

Comment: @darijan, what are you saying? The signature is correct for an implementation of Comparable<MyPosition>. What other implementation do you mean?

Comment: @Tony, what data type does `o.getPriority()` return?

Comment: @Ernest what are you talking about? I did not comment anything. I just posted an answer below.

Comment: I'm talking about the comment you deleted. Not funny, son.

Comment: Sorry dad. My dad is so cool, we goof around like this all the time.

Comment: @EyalSchneider Is there any other methods to re-organize besides removeall and addall again.

Comment: @ErnestFriedman-Hill Sorry, it is int.

Comment: Then you could (should) replace the whole body of your compareTo method with "return new Integer(o.getPriority()).compareTo(new Integer(getPriority()));"

Comment: @ErnestFriedman-Hill I want to make the edge of highest priority stay at the head of queue,but I guess it will make the edge of lowest priority stay at the head. Is that true? Thank you.

Comment: JUst reverse which object is used first in the expression to swap the order -- if you use getPriority() before o.getPriority(), the order will go the other way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java PriorityQueues are implemented as heaps. So the compareTo() is evaluated at insertion time.

One of The problems you might be facing is that you may not be overriding the correct method (as others have pointed out). Add an @Override annotation to your compareTo() method and the compiler will tell you if you're not doing what you think you're doing (if you're using Java 1.5 or newer).

Here is code:

```
public class MyPosition implements Comparable<MyPosition>{
    private Integer priority;

    @Override
    public int compareTo(MyPosition that) {
        return this.priority.compareTo(that.priority);
    }
}
```

Comment: But if I want the edge of high priority to stay at the head, how should I do?

Comment: Since they are evaluated at insertion time, Like Eyal Schneider said, you need to dequeue and requeue the item. Since you haven't really shown how you handle the different "My Positions" it's a little difficult to say, but I assume that when you're drawing them, is a natural time to dequeue and requeue items? You could have like a double queueing system, where you dequeue from queue a, draw the item, change it's properties, and the requeue on queue b. then when you're done switch queues a and b, and go again. But like I said it's hard to say without seeing more code. Sorry.

Comment: @MikkelLøkke any idea why `that` in your example code would ever be null? It's not easily reproducible, but I've witnessed a state where NPE was thrown from `compareTo()` every time it tried to `add()` to the `PriorityQueue`.

Comment: Queue implementations generally do not allow insertion of null elements, although some implementations, such as LinkedList, do not prohibit insertion of null. Even in the implementations that permit it, null should not be inserted into a Queue, as null is also used as a special return value by the poll method to indicate that the queue contains no elements. 
 https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html

Comment: I'm not really sure what sensible semantic value you could possibly get from inserting a null value, or even an item without a valid priority into a PriorityQueue.

Answer (score 0):

Try implementing your `compareTo` by utilizing the `compareTo` method of an `Integer` class:

```
public int compareTo(MyPosition o) {
    return Integer.valueOf(getPriority()).compareTo(Integer.valueOf(o.getPriority()));
}
```

One of the errors I see here is that you compare objects with `==` sign. While it works for primitive types (e.g. `int`) and in some cases for `Integer` it gives wrong results for larger numbers. It does not seem that this is a problem in your example but I just wanted to point this out. Objects should be compared for equality with `equals()` method.

Another problem might be that you did not implement the `Comparable` interface in your `MyPosition` class.